# select multiple fields in join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am trying to group by magnitudId and return an anonymous type containing fields MagnitudID, CalibracionID and MaxDate in order to then join by calibracionVerificacionId but below linq query is not working:

```
   (from c in equipo.CalibracionVerificacion
    join c2 in
        (from c3 in equipo.CalibracionVerificacion
         where c3.equipoId == equipo.equipoId && !(c3.magnitudId == null || c3.magnitudId.Trim() == string.Empty)
         group c3 by c3.magnitudId into cgroup
         select new
         {
             MagnitudID = cgroup.Key,
             CalibracionID = cgroup.Select(x => x.calibracionVerificacionId),
             MaxDate = cgroup.Max(x => x.fechaPrevista),
         }
        ) on c.calibracionVerificacionId equals c2.CalibracionID
    where c.equipoId == equipo.equipoId
    select c).Min(d => d.fechaPrevista);
```

Comment: The code isn't helping here. Want to share a schema of your data structures? and also an example of the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are asking. It looks like you're joining the same list on itself, then grouping and then selecting the min of the max date?

If so, maybe this will work for you:

```
void Main()
{
    var CalibracionVerificacion = new List<Equipo>();

    var results = CalibracionVerificacion       
        .Join(
            CalibracionVerificacion.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.magnitudId)), 
            c1 => c1.equipoId, 
            c2 => c2.equipoId, 
            (c1, c2) => new {c1, c2})
        .GroupBy(x => x.c2.magnitudId)
        .Select(g => new
        {
            MagnitudID = g.Key,
            CalibracionID = g.Select(x => x.c1.calibracionVerificacionId),
            MaxDate = g.Max(x => x.c1.fechaPrevista)
        })
        .Min(g => g.MaxDate);   

}

class Equipo {
    public int equipoId  { get; set; }
    public string magnitudId  { get; set; }
    public int calibracionVerificacionId { get; set; }
    public int fechaPrevista  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If the above solved your question, then please mark it as a solution, if not, then please let me know how I can help.